# Find Minimize $B=8x+\dfrac{6}{x}+18y+\dfrac{7}{y} $

Tags: inequality

For $x,y$ are positive real number satisfy $\frac{4}{x}+\frac{5}{y}\geq 23$. Find Minimize $$B=8x+\dfrac{6}{x}+18y+\dfrac{7}{y} $$

---

i think :
 $$B=8x+\dfrac{6}{x}+18y+\dfrac{7}{y}=\left(8x+\dfrac{2}{x}\right)+\left(18y+\dfrac{2}{y}\right)+\left(\dfrac{4}{x}+\dfrac{5}{y}\right)\ge8+12+23=43$$

i need new method

Comment: where is an equation above?

Comment: oh, verry sorry

Comment: $43$ is the right result, and the equal sign, when  does it hold?

Comment: when x=1/2;y=2/3 ?

Comment: @WordShallow.: you mean at $x=1/2$, $y=1/3$.

Comment: yeah , thank you @aravind

Comment: Your result is correct (as far as I can see) and sharp. Why do you need a "new method"?

Comment: @MartinR How can we be sure that this is minimum? Is there a general method or a proof for this?

Comment: You have shown that $B \ge 43$ under the given condition.For $x=1/2, y=1/3$ (which satisfy the condition) you get $B = 43$. Therefore the lower bound  $43$ is best possible.

Comment: But there are many values other values (hyperbola) for which the condition is true, so how to be sure that this is indeed minimum?